# Updating a single .NET assembly in a production environment

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, deployment, webforms, .net-assembly

Does anyone know whether it is 100% safe to replace (copy + paste) an assembly with an updated version of itself, where all version history (AssemblyInfo.vb) is exactly the same but the only difference being that a minor code change took place in one of the aspx.vb files.

Comment: The answer to this question completely depends on what you mean by "minor code change". For most small changes it will be fine, but of course there are several types of changes (modifying constants, enums, method signatures, etc.) that would result in breaking changes. Therefore, in general, it is **not 100% safe**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is safe if you are sure you didn't break your existing code (method doesn't exist anymore, ...).
If you manually load assemblies make sure to update versions and tokens.

If you are not sure you can duplicate your website into another folder, create a test IIS instance and test the deployment of single files.

Keep in mind that a clean deployment is safe rather than single file deployments that may cause breaking changes if you are not extremely careful. This may not be a problem on test instances but should never be done on Live.

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible and very easily doable but it can easily become a habit that can have a negative impact when the production system is becoming very large, possibly unstable and have a large number of users.

There are a couple of ways I would suggest trying or to be mindful of:

- Create a installer or multiple installers depending on the projects
  in you solution. These installer produce te excutable(s) to install
  on the production server. This will be done manually. Backup the previous
  installers for rollback.
- You can create a [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384248%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) application. This can be run manually and also can be scheduled using a stable scheduling app.
- One can also make use of [Visual Studio's publishing function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1y1404zt%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). After
  compiling code and setting it to release mode it gets publish via
  file/network/ftp on the production space. This replaces all the markup files and assemblies.
- The automate the process you can use a [TFS Builder server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms181709%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and
  schedule daily or weekly builds. These installations can be made
  manually or one can use SMS(Microsoft System Management Services) to
  schedule timely installations
- One can use [Windows Powershell](http://devinfra-us.blogspot.com/2011/02/using-powershell-20-from-aspnet-part-1.html) as well

TFS Build Server and SMS carry cost implications of course but it
will be a small price to pay if problems on a production environment
can bring a company down.

There are a couple of ways to do this. See what might work and get into good habits when it comes to an **production environment**